# How do I rotate and then scale an image within a scrollview?

Tags: iphone, rotation, scrollview, cgaffinetransform

I want to scale an image after rotating it using CGAffineTransformMakeRotation.
When I simply pass the imageview in viewForZoomingInScrollView, scaling does not work once I have rotated my image.
Any ideas?Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the image view within a `UIView` instance and then rotate that instance using `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation`. I had an image view as a subview of a scroll view. Then I did this,

```
UIView * view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.imageView.frame];
[view addSubview:self.imageView];
[self.scrollView addSubview:view];

view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
```

Return the `imageView` as the view for zooming. It should work.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately it shows the same behavior. When the image is not in rotated state, the zoom works perfectly, but when the image is rotated, as soon as I touch the screen and try to zoom, the image disappears completely and all I can see is the scrollview background.

Comment: Take a look at [`this example`](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22783696/ImageScrollZoom.zip)

Comment: @Deepak, Thanks for your reply and code. I have modified it slightly and added a slider, which will control the rotation angle. You can first rotate the image using the slider and then try to zoom it, and you will understand my problem. I realise now that it must be something to do with my scrollview content or axis of rotation, but cannot figure out the exact issue. The code is [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/32516710/ImageScrollZoom-1.zip)

Comment: You were trying to rotate the image view rather than the container view. I adjusted the code to rotate the container view. You can get the code from the same link as in the last comment.